# How to remove extra spaces from powershell generated file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to extract a series of lines from a source file. The code works, even looks fine, but when viewed from FTP software, and on the actual machine, it has too many spaces between characters.

> source.csv:
> SRC_NAME,NOTF_UC_TYPE,NOTF_SCN_ID,DLV_ADDR_TYPE,DLV_ADDR_ID,AccountNo
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 11234567 108,13457890
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12234567 108,32457890
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12334567 108,34357890
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12344567 108,34547890
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12345567 108,34575890

> search.txt:
> 12234567
> 12345567
> 12344567

> ExpectedOutput.csv:
> SRC_NAME,NOTF_UC_TYPE,NOTF_SCN_ID,DLV_ADDR_TYPE,DLV_ADDR_ID,AccountNo
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12234567 108,3457890
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12345567 108,3457890
> BPS,1,150,3,0.0.0.1 /billinfo 12344567 108,3457890

> Output received:
> ÿþS R C _ N A M E , N O T F _ U C _ T Y P E , N O T F _ S C N _ I D , D L V _ A D D R _ T Y P E , D L V _  A D D R _ I D , A c c o u n t N o
> B P S , 1 , 1 5 0 , 3 , 0 . 0 . 0 . 1   / b i l l i n f o   1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7   1 0 8 , 3 4 5 7 8 9 0
> B P S , 1 ,1 5 0 , 3 , 0 . 0 . 0 . 1   / b i l l i n f o   1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7   1 0 8 , 3 4 5 7 8 9 0 
> B P S , 1 ,1 5 0 , 3 , 0 . 0 . 0 . 1   / b i l l i n f o   1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7   1 0 8 , 3 4 5 7 8 9 0

Script used:

```
#copy the header
Get-Content .\source.csv -First 1 > ExpectedOutput.csv -Encoding ASCII

#search the contents of search.txt in source.csv and append to the ExpectedOutput.csv file
get-content .\source.csv |
    select-string -Pattern (Get-Content .\search.txt) |
    Add-Content ExpectedOutput.csv -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Try  utf 8 instead

Comment: that two-chars-per thing usually indicates an encoding problem. as AbrahamZinala indicated, try a different encoding - one that is inherently multi-byte.

Comment: Are you sure that these are spaces?

Comment: @harrymc - yes, those are spaces.

Comment: Perhaps you should post online the source files.

Comment: `ÿþ` are the two bytes that make the BOM for UTF-16 Little-Endian ('Unicode') `0xff 0xfe`. The output is stored with that encoding. Either change the way you save the extracted lines by using `-Encoding UTF8` or use `-Encoding Unicode` when opening the recieved output file.

Answer (score 0):

Since these scripts are being run manually, a workaround is:

1. Instead of directly opening in the FTP, open the generated CSV in notepad/text
   editor on your local system.
2. Copy the entire contents and paste the same in the file on
   the FTP software
3. The new file doesn't have the extra spaces.

This is a rudimentary but assured way of getting this done.

Comment: As the other users already pointed out those characters are no spaces. You simply have to use a text editor that is capable of UTF-16 (e.g. Notepad++).